# String with spaces with getline(cin,str); error

Tags: c++, string, spaces

In a swicth there are a case:

```
case 3:
    cout << "Digite la palabra que desea añadir: ";
    cin >> word;
    cout << "Digite el significado de la palabra: ";
    getline(cin,auxstr);
    result = addWord(word,auxstr);
```

but when I compile & run the program it's as if I pressed enter to getline without allow me enter a line:

```
Digite la opción adecuada: 3
Digite la palabra que desea añadir: a
Digite el significado de la palabra: La palabra a ha sido añadida con éxito en el diccionario
```

"La palabra a ha sido añadida con éxito en el diccionario" is the output of addWord function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [over 9000 other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+getline+not+waiting).

Comment: Pon ``cin.get()`` antes de ``getline(cin,auxstr);``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have the `'\n'` from the previous line in the buffer, so when `getline` tries to get the input from the buffer, it only takes the `'\n'` and assumes the job is done, not allowing you to input anything else.

Just put `cin.get()` before `getline(cin,auxstr);`